# Refresing an image in jsp without reloading the whole page

Tags: html, jsp

```
<c:if test="${commandObject.function.functionCode =='ELOG WELCOME'}">
    <td align="left" width="28">
        <img src="assets/images/welcome/kewill_logo_new.jpg" width="100" height="28" alt="Logo" position = "center"/>
    </td>

    </c:if>
```

I am using the above condition to put an image on a jsp, but the image should be removed if the above condition is not satisfied.
The problem is that the image is not removing, it remains there when the condition is not satisfied when jsp loads next time.

But once I refresh the page the image goes. I want the image to disappear whenever the condition is not true without having to refresh the whole page. How can I do that? Any 
working solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line of code :

```
<%TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); %>
```

It reloads the page once for 5 seconds i.e. it will provide a time delay of 5 seconds on any action performed..
I used it to solve the similar kind of problem in my project..Difference is just that you are removing image and I was forming image on action of button click..

Comment: do you just have to place the code? Cause it's saying cannot be resolved to be a type.

Comment: If it is JSP page then yes just place the code and import the required package it asks for

Comment: which package that would be?

Comment: i did this in my jsp : <%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>

Comment: is that all required ?

Comment: You have to import this package <%@page import="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit"%>